How can I access an extension preferences with python?
I would like to make a mini backup python script of 4.2 extension.
The old method can access to the preference like below.
addon_prefs = bpy.context.preferences.addons['auto_rig_pro-master'].preferences
basePath = r"/mypath//"
addon_prefs.custom_armatures_path = basePath + "Armatures Presets"


but new extension method can't access by ARP_MT_arp_addon_preferences.custom_armatures_path.
How could do I do?

How can I change Blender's Scripts Path in preferences with Python?

Have you tried bpy.context.preferences.addons[__package__].preferences ?

what do you mean by "new extension method can't access by ARP_MT_arp_addon_preferences.custom_armatures_path ? It doesn't seem relevant to the code you show above, and that code works on my end. Though admittedly this a legacy addon, not an extension. Do you mean to ask the equivalent for extensions?

Thank you for reply! Are your Auto-rig version is older than 3.72.23? This code was fine till previous one.

no i use that very version

The method hasn't changed AFAIK, but I reckon the module names are a bit different. While legacy addons ca be assumed to simply be the .py's name or module folder's name, the extensions' module seem to be prefixed with bl_ext.blender_org.. (And perhaps extensions from platforms other than the BF's official extensions platform would have their kwn prefix too?.)
Regardless, if you want to be sure of the module name to use, you could always ask Blender directly, in its Python console:
>>> print(*bpy.context.preferences.addons.keys(), sep='\n')
io_curve_svg
io_mesh_uv_layout
io_scene_fbx
io_scene_gltf2
cycles
rigify
node_wrangler
bl_ext.blender_org.viewport_pie_menus
bl_ext.blender_org.amaranth
bl_ext.blender_org.screencast_keys
bl_ext.blender_org.matalogue
(and so on...)

Then you can copy and paste in a text editor to search what you want.
3D Viewport Pie Menus is an extension, we can see it in the list as bl_ext.blender_org.viewport_pie_menus. So its preferences are accessible from bpy.context.preferences.addons['bl_ext.blender_org.viewport_pie_menus'].preferences. Proof:


You are right! I can find those from print. "bl_ext.user_default.skin_selection" "bl_ext.user_default.auto_rig_pro_quick_rig" "bl_ext.user_default.auto_rig_pro"
